# How can I distinguish between "to stream video" as "to broadcast video" and "to watch video"?

Tags: meaning, differences

If I say I'm streaming PUBG on Twitch, does it mean I'm broadcasting my gameplay on Twitch or I'm watching someone playing PUBG on Twitch?

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stream) "stream" has a meaning which is to listen to or watch sound or video on a computer directly from the internet rather than downloading it and saving it first.

Comment: It means both—the broadcaster is upstreaming, the viewer is downstreaming (these two words are not in common usage with regards to video streaming), both of which are types of streaming.

Comment: Yes nd underneath Janus' clear response, please consider how nearly everyone uses *download* to mean either *download* or *upload*.

there is almost no possibility of correcting that misuse and every likelihood that *stream* will soon fall foul of the same failure.

To me the main hope would seem to be ignore the largely pointless *stream* and try to use the accurate *broadcast* or * watch*…

How much chance would you give that, though?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin is it really true that *"nearly everyone uses download to mean either download or upload."*?

Comment: Well, doubtless not the average goatherd in Outer Mongolia but generally, Max, when was the last time you heard Mr Average User distinguish between up- or downloading?

Answer (score 1):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stream)  has it right.

If you were playing the game on  Twitch, you were not [broadcasting it.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/broadcast)  For now the term *broadcast* still has the traditional meaning of scatter over a wide area. The internet does not *broadcast*, and, despite hacking, is actually [a closed circuit](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/closed+circuit).

In short, whether you are watching someone play a game on the internet, or playing it yourself, you are streaming it. If someone is watching you play, that person is streaming your play. As always, new terms will become current, such as [podcast](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/podcast). For now, stream is the most used term for both transmit and receive on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

One of the senses of the the verb **stream** implies "transfer", "movement", and "continuity". It does not necessarily mean watching/listening.

You may stream a video / sound to PS4, TV, MP3 player from your computer and watch it real-time.

[The free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stream) defines stream as:

> To transmit or receive (audio or video content), especially over the
>   internet, in small, sequential packets that permit the content to be
>   played continuously as it is being received and without saving it to a
>   hard disk.